# How to get an array value from Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic3

I have the data structure illustrated below stored in Cloud Firestore. I have saved company record in Firestore database and i want to check my domain is exist in company's domain array or not and if yes then i want all company data in response but i have no idea how can i achieve this with Firestore.

[image]

Here i have marked domains. let me explain more,
For Example if my domain name is "abcinfo.in" then i want to check that is it already exist with any partner_company domains or not and here it is linked with this partner_company so it should return me all data of partner_company. That's it.

I have tried with below code but it helps when there are single value but here i need to check from array

```
 var domaindata = db.collection('partner_company').where('company_domain', '==', _user.domain);
  domaindata.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
      console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
    });
  });
```

So please suggest me any better way to achieve data that i want.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var domaindata = db.collection('partner_company').where('company_domain', 'array-contains', _user.domain);
```

This will check if the array `company_domain` contains the domain passed.

Check the following:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership

Answer (score 2):

Firebase comes with a neat feature for array filtering: **array-contains** and **array-contains-any**. They can be used as a query operator.

Use array-contains to filter arrays for values that have to match perfectly.
The following query would resolve your test document:

```
db.collection('partner_company').where('company_domain', 'array-contains', ['abcinfo.in', 'newtest.com'];
```

array-contains-any on the other side filters for at least one matching value.

```
db.collection('partner_company').where('company_domain', 'array-contains-any', ['definfo.in', 'newtest.com'];
```

Read more about array membership in firebase [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership)